# Access to multiple mp4 files as one from the internet

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video, mp4, libav

I have files with names like

```
10.06.2014.12.05.mp4
10.06.2014.12.06.mp4
10.06.2014.12.07.mp4
.....
```

Is it possible to access them as single file, like 10.06.2014.mp4 from a browser?

All files has the same format and duration.

Comment: Your question is not clear, Please add more information...

Comment: Browser send get query to file 10.06.2014. Server send first file.
Then Browser seek to 2.01 for example. Server send 1-st second from file 10.06.2014.12.07.mp4 etc.

Comment: You have the privilege to edit your post with all details, don't be lazy to add enough information if you need help ... Which language or framework are you using? add more, add more, add more!!!

Comment: All what you write it is not important. I don't need help in  implementation. I'm ask how to do that with html5 and server on other side. Just protocol.

Comment: Well, in that case if its not important for us to know enough information, Good luck at getting someone who will magically guess the answer you need!